# What is the difference between basic authentication and cryptographic authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography, basic-authentication

What are the main differences between these two authentication methods?
And when would you use one over the other?

Comment: Answered without thinking, but these kind of questions really belong on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @owlstead I tried doing that for some other questions, but they redirected my questions here.

Comment: It depends on the question asked. This one does not include any programming related information at all, the other questions you asked up to now were all programming language related (Java and Dart to be precise). If you cannot think of an IDE or language tag or if it is not about general programming principles ([tag:language-agnostic]) then it probably does not belong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic authentication is just [sending the username + password to the server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_Authentication_Protocol).

Cryptographic authentication is a generic term that may include any kind of authentication that uses cryptographic algorithms to authenticate the entities. Most of the time it will consist of a [challenge response protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol), where the response is created by encrypting or keyed hashing over the challenge. As only the person that knows the key (/password) is able to create a cryptogram that way, the other party knows who has performed the authentication.

Note that basic authentication over SSL/TLS is generally more secure than cryptographic authentication over an unprotected HTTP transport layer. In the end this does depend the details of the system though.